# How to explicitly capture a macro inside a lambda capture?

Tags: c++, lambda, macros

I have a lambda and want to print the name of the function the lambda is defined in. If I use `__FUNCTION__` inside the lambda, it'll just print `operator()`, which is reasonable since that's the function the macro is in.

However, Clang-Tidy warns about this and mentions the following:

> Clang-Tidy: Inside a lambda, '__FUNCTION__' expands to the name of the function call operator; consider capturing the name of the enclosing function explicitly

Is there any way I can capture the name of the enclosing function **without** declaring it before the lambda with `const char* name = __FUNCTION__` and capture `name`. I.e. something like this:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    [&__FUNCTION__](){
        std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << std::endl;  // Should print "main".
    }();

    return 0;
}
```

The code above obviously won't work as the macro will expand in the preprocessing stage.

The reason for the restriction is because everything is inside a macro that's going to be used in an expression, but I still want to run some statements. For example:

```
#define ALLOCATE(allocator, size) [&](){                                            \
    std::cout << "Allocating in " << __FILE__ << ":" << __FUNCTION__ << std::endl;  \        
    return allocator.allocate(size);                                                \
}()
```

Comment: @cigien Yeah, I think it seems to be a reasonable duplicate. While the questions don't quite originate from the same base question, they're similar enough that the other would've answered this one as well.

Comment: Ok, sounds good. This is a useful signpost I think, so thanks for posting it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, since C++14 it's possible to use lambda capture initializers which allows arbitrary expressions to be captured by name. So a solution is:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    [function_name=__FUNCTION__](){
        std::cout << function_name << std::endl;  // Prints "main".
    }();

    return 0;
}
```